# YouTube-dl - autonumber to distinguish between different playlists mentioned in batch-file?

Tags: youtube-dl

My **youtube-dl.conf** is -

```
-u <User Name>
-p <Password>
-i
-c
--no-warnings
--console-title
--batch-file='batch-file.txt'
--autonumber-size 3 
-o 'MyVideos/%(playlist_title)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s'
-f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]'
```

### batch-file.txt

```
URL1
URL2
URL3
```

The problem is, when I put multiple playlist in the batch file, the autonumber can not distinguish between different playlists.

For Example, if URL1 (Which is an URL of a Playlist) has 21 videos, and the last video has the autonumber 21, then the URL2 (second playlist) will have 22 as the autonumber of its first video.

I want each playlist to start with 1.

Is there any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually contacted youtube-dl and they gave me the following solution.

```
-u <User Name>
-p <Password>
-i
-c
--no-warnings
--console-title
--batch-file='batch-file.txt'
-o 'MyVideos/%(playlist_title)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s'
-f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]'
```

Instead of (autonumber)s, just use (playlist_index)s